# Conceptual doubts in EM waves and old quantum theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation

I have a few questions.

1. I know that EM waves transfer energy. So when they are generated why do they form curves? Are energy packets moving in a curvy path, or energy packets (quanta) not considered when wave is propagating? OR are the electric and magnetic FIELDS curvy in nature? NUTSHELL: Why is the EM wave curly and how do we know that they are curvy?
2. When ever we heat an object, the energy supplied makes the electrons oscillate due to which they radiate electromagnetic waves of which frequency rises as temperature rises. At certain temp. First, the red colour comes and then as we heat further blue comes because frequency is rising, my interpretation says that if we heat it further the object would radiate waves with frequency higher than the visible range and we couldn't be able to see the object glow. Am I right?
   The main thing is that books write that waves are formed because electrons oscillate and they want to become stable but atoms are also moving when heated and so the positive nucleus is also oscillating due to which EM waves should be produced because whenever charged objects accelerate they radiate energy. First of all, is this true? Second of all, why do they radiate energy? Is to become stable or something like that?
3. I attended a lecture which said that every object is radiating energy But I don't understand why? Is this because of environment? Or is it because electrons are oscillating and radiating energy or something like that?
4. The famous question that electron have uniform centripetal acceleration so they would radiate energy and spiral  in to the  nucleus! Why can't a body moving at a uniform velocity in an Electromagnetic field radiate off its energy? What is so special about accelerated Motion?
5. The Bohr model was proposed to solve this major problem, by postulating that the energy is quantised.

I don't understand this, So what if energy is quantised? How does this means that energy cant be radiated (or absorbed?)?

Comment: Can you post these as separate questions. Re your first question, EM waves don't move in curves. Are you thinking about *field lines*?

Comment: Re #3, if there's no acceleration, then an inertial frame exists in which the charge is at rest and stays at rest, so it has no kinetic energy to turn into radiation.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 I know that EM waves transfer energy.So when they are generated WHY do they form a CURVE....are energy packets moving in a curvy path , or energy packets(quanta) not considered when wave is propagating.... OR are the electric and magnetic FIELDS curvy in nature....NUTSHELL(Why wave are curvy and how do we know that they are curvy)

[Electromagnetic waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_waves) are not curvy. The curves in figure 1 are the amplitudes of the field and are not displacements in space. The energy the waves carry goes in straight lines. Waves follow [wave mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Wave_mechanics).

> 2.when ever we heat an object, the energy supplied makes the electrons oscillate due to which they radiate electromagnetic waves of which frequency rises as temperature rises.....at certain temp. first the red color comes and then as we heat further blue comes because frequency is rising, my interpretation says that if we heat it further the object would radiate waves with frequency higher than the visible range and we couldn't be able to see the object glow...is it true!!!! THE main thing is that books write that waves are formed because electrons oscillate and they want to become stable but atoms are also moving when heated and so the positive nucleus is also oscillating due to which EM waves should be Produce because whenever charge objects accelerate they radiate energy.....first of all is this true and why do they radiate energy to become stable or what....

You are totally confused on this . See my answer to a [similar  question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68684/does-matter-radiate-energy/68685#68685) which covers this.

> I attended a lecture which said that every object is radiating energy BUT WHY ...is this because of environment or because electrons are oscillating and radiating energy or what!!

It is because of quantum statistical mechanics. The atoms and molecules are neutral but their electric and magnetic fields are distorted and these have many energy levels which absorb and release photons. These energy levels depend on the temperature. Statistically the higher the temperature the higher the energy differences in the energy levels . The radiation that is not absorbed, i.e. find an energy level to absorb it on its path in matter, radiates to the environment and is the black body radiation.

> 4.The famous question that electron move in circular accelerated motion so they would radiate energy and fall into nucleus!!!! a.why cant uniform velocity of any charged body produce electromagnetic radiation,whats so special about accelerated Motion...... b. The Bohr model was proposed to solve this, by stipulating that the orbits were closed and quantized and no energy could be lost while the electron was in orbit, thus creating the stability of the atom necessary to form solids and liquids.
>
> I DON'T UNDERSTAND THIS STATEMENT, if energy is quantised(does this means that energy cant be radiated or absorbed!!!!)

Absolutely yes. Quantization is the reason that the electrons around the atoms do not radiate.

> the electrons should always radiate energy if they are accelerating which they do i think.... so whatsoever Bohr gave the reason , but still what stops electrons from radiating energy........

Accelerating electrons do radiate, but the electrons in the orbitals about the nuclei of atoms are not accelerating because they are not orbiting like planets as the heuristic Bohr model proposed, but are following solutions of  quantum mechanical equations which give the probability of finding the electron in the (x,y,z) of the orbital when one tries to  measure it. The solution is not an orbit.

From this you must understand that a course in quantum mechanics is necessary before you can understand really the answers to your questions.

> these are the basics of mine and i want to clear them all with a good satisfactory reasoning please try to give help which covers my these doubts conceptually....

If you are really interested in physics you should take courses that automatically answer such basic questions.