# Which phenomenon makes the electrons revolve around the nucleus instead of crashing into it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, orbitals

If the system has to gain stability, the electrons must crash into the nucleus but that's not the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't electrons crash into the nuclei they "orbit"?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/)

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted this, it's a good question to ask (though it's been asked here before).

Comment: @KyleKanos  It is a good question, and I don't think anyone should get downvoted for asking a duplicate. It would be nice, however, for people to check the site for an answer before they post.

Comment: Look in the "linked" sidebar of the earlier version for an idea of how often this has been asked.

Comment: I forgot to search whether the question was asked  earlier