# Why does Bohr's stationary orbits not radiate energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

I am presently in high school trying to understand the Bohr's theory. I somewhat familiar with Maxwell's laws but very soon I'll learn about them thoroughly. So please could anyone explain with respect to the EM theory why does Bohr's stationery orbit does not radiate energy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't electrons crash into the nuclei they "orbit"?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bohr model is not correct. Bohr proposed that electrons could not lose energy in orbit (because they could only be in certain orbits) as a postulate.

[image]

At n = 1 he said that the electron just didn't have anywhere else to go.

Another explanation is the Uncertainty Principle. If the electron is in the nucleus we would know its momentum and position exactly.

Answer (score 1):

> So please could anyone explain with respect to the EM theory why does Bohr's stationery orbit does not radiate energy?

It is the assumption Bohr made. He assumed there are special orbits that have an exception from the laws of electromagnetic theory.