# Why don't we consider the electromagnetic field in the equations of Bohr's theory of atoms?

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, coulombs-law

**hi,i know these, my mean that the magnitude magnetic field B formule that i find here** 
my question is that we consider Coulomb force in [Bohr's theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) but don't consider the electromagnetic field? An accelerated charge has  magnetic field according Maxwell's theory.

Why don't we consider the electromagnetic field in the equations of Bohr's theory of atoms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't electrons crash into the nuclei they "orbit"?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/)

Comment: i isn't  this question,i was going to find  magnetic formula     B that i answered in below.

Answer (score 2):

The [Bohr model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) is a phenomenological model in analogy to the planetary model. The electric field is a part of the electro magnetic field. Qualitatively, a negative charge orbiting a positive charge is expected to emit electromagnetic radiation , and in the classical model it is expected they will fall on each other. The data Bohr fitted, the [Lyman and Balmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series) series, showed a discrete spectrum for hydrogen, not a continuum.

In such a model  the stability of the orbits has to be postulated, that the electrons could only radiate in transition between fixed orbits in discrete steps corresponding to the observations.

So in a sense the model goes beyond classical electromagnetism, and it needed the development of quantum mechanics and quantum electrodynamics for mathematical accuracy in modelling atoms.

Comment: hi,i know these, my mean that the magnitude magnetic field B formule that i find here     http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node125.html

Comment: A rotating charge is not uniformly moving, it has angular acceleration. It is this angular acceleration that should give the electromagnetic field, not a B field.