# Magnetic induction (electron in hydrogen)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, atomic-physics, electromagnetic-induction

In hydrogen atom, the electron is making 6.6*10^15 revolutions per second in circular path of radius 0.53ang. what is the magnetic induction produced at the center of orbit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the magnetic field due to a revolving electron of hydrogen atom in first orbit](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264123/)

Answer (score 0):

A electron revolving in a circular orbit may be treated as current flowing in a circular ring. We are to find magnetic induction at the centre of this ring.

The current $i=e/T=Ef$.

Here $f$ is the frequency of revolution of electron.

The formula for magnetic induction at the centre of a current carrying ring is(which I hope you know)$$B=\frac{\mu_0 i}{2r}$$

Just substitute $ i$ in the above equation.

So your answer in terms of variables is:$$\frac{\mu_0 ef}{2r}$$