# Planetary model of the atom: crossed electro-magnetic field generated by rotating electron

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrons, classical-electrodynamics, atoms

In the planetary model of an atom (however invalid), the electrons rotating around the proton are discrete charges moving in a circular motion, which means that there is a finite current in a circular loop. [This current leads to a magnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264123/how-to-find-the-magnetic-field-due-to-a-revolving-electron-of-hydrogen-atom-in-f) perpendicular in direction to the plane of rotation of the electron, via the Biot-Savart law. Then, is there a fundamental reason why the motion of the electrons is not [modeled as a charged particle in a *crossed* electro-magnetic field, leading to cycloidal trajectories](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_29.html) in the plane of the electron's motion?

Comment: What is the direction of the field at the position of the electron?

Comment: Good question! At the position of the electron, the Biot-Savart law would imply that the magnetic field does not exist, so that the crossed electro-magnetic field does not exist in the circular path of the electron, thus making the question ill-posed. However, the crossed electro-magnetic field will exist in other atoms with multiple electrons in orbit.

Comment: @kb314 that is why quantum mechanics was needed. to get rid of orbits among other things