# Why doesn't electron collide with nucleus?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, atoms

We know that electrons go round the nucleus. But in my textbook, it is written that Rutherford's model was incomplete as the electrons would collide with the nucleus because of Maxwell's law.

But in Bohr's model, the problem remains. Because even in this model the electrons go round the necleus.

So

1. Is Bohr's model incomplete in this sense? Or
2. Is Maxwell's theory incomplete?

Comment: Bohr's model is incomplete!

Comment: @AndreiGeanta So you're saying that Bohr is wrong and Maxwell is right. Then what is the right model and how does it overcome Maxwell's difficulty?

Comment: @AsifIqubal, Please check if you can find the answer in the post that JohnRennie gave you. The "right" model is the one that uses Quantum Mechanics. [You can solve the hydrogen atom using the Schrodinger equation](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~srk/Ay126/Lectures/Lecture3/SchrodingerModel.pdf).

Comment: @AndreiGeanta Sorry, I read in only 10th grade. So quantum mechanics hasn't become my thing.

Comment: Ok, @AsifIqubal, no problem. But that is how things behave at that level. You can't fully explain the atom without quantum mechanics.

Comment: Actually Asif, quantum mechanics  and its radical redefinition of nature at the microscopic level became necessary also due to : "why the electrons  do not fall on the nucleus". The Bohr model made a postulate that angular momentum was quantized, and thus stable orbits could be assumed to exist. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Bohr.html#c4 . Quantum mechanics is a general theoretical framework with postulates which impose quantization of energy and other variables, depending on boundary conditions, and fixed energy levels . http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html

Comment: Actually they sometimes do "crash" into the nucleus: although this is not quite what your question is getting at, such a "crash" is the mechanism behind [electron capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture), leading to a nuclear transmutation.

Comment: @AndreiGeanta Does 'The Uncertainty Principle' has something to do with this?

Comment: @AndreiGeanta Does Maxwell's law work for atoms or in atomic scale?

Comment: @AsifIqubal, It really depends on the problem you want to solve. It's like asking: does Newton's law of gravity work on the Solar System scale? It does work to some extent, but you will get more accurate results if you use The General Theory of Relativity. Here, as StephenG said, a more complete theory of the electromagnetic fields is Quantum ElectroDynamics (QED). QED is a theory that takes into account the relativistic effects and the quantum nature of the electromagnetic fields and it describes the interaction between light and matter.

Comment: Yes, @AsifIqubal the uncertainty principle has very much to do with this.

Comment: @AsifIqubal, [If we try to confine our electrons in a region that is very close to the protons, then according to the uncertainty principle they must have some mean square momentum which is larger the more we try to confine them. It is this motion, required by the laws of quantum mechanics, that keeps the electrical attraction from bringing the charges any closer together.](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_01.html#Ch1-S1)

Answer (score 1):

The question about electrons not crashing into the nucleus is answered is the duplicate [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20003/why-dont-electrons-crash-into-the-nuclei-they-orbit).

To directly answer your questions :

> Is Bohr's model incomplete in this sense?

Not even incomplete.  It's essentially an empirical rule used to fit the data but without a real basis for it's assumptions.  It was, however, a stepping stone to more complete quantum theories.

> Is Maxwell's theory incomplete?

Surprisingly yes.  Although in a practical sense Maxwell's theory is perfectly usable for real problems, a more complete (or more fundamental, if you prefer) theory of electromagnetic fields was developed called [Quantum ElectroDynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) (QED for short).

And it's worth noting that quantum field theories are also incomplete in the sense that we cannot build a working one that incorporates gravity.  You never really get a "complete" theory, you get a "good enough" theory that matches what we see and can measure.  And that theory becomes "incomplete" when it doesn't fully explain something we see or measure.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where electrons do crash into the nuclei they orbit, and this is known as electron capture.

> Electron capture is a process in which the proton-rich nucleus of an electrically neutral atom absorbs an inner atomic electron, usually from the K or L electron shell.

It is also a method for which some unstable isotopes decay.