# Why do electrons fall into the nucleus in Rutherford's model of the atom but not in Bohr's model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

In Rutherford's atomic model, an atom's nucleus can't survive because of the electromagnetic theory of Maxwell. But in Bohr's model it can survive.

My question is: in both atomic models, electrons move around the nucleus. But then why do electrons fall into the nucleus in Rutherford's model, thus making the atom unstable, while in Bohr's model the atom survives?

Comment: Bohr’s model didn’t solve the ‘lots of charge in a small volume’ problem. It was taken as a fact after Rutherford. Of course, that led to nuclear physics...

Comment: Related: [Why don't electrons crash into the nuclei they orbit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/)

Answer (score 3):

Funny question. It is precisely "to avoid Rutherford's problem". Bohr's model consists of three **postulates**, which means that Bohr **suggests** it is like that. He assumes that it is like he says, without specifying why. He takes that as true, and then he derives his results.

Among the postulates, there are (from Wikipedia):

> 1. Electrons in atoms orbit the nucleus.
> 2. The electrons can only orbit
>    stably, without radiating, in certain orbits (called by Bohr the
>    "stationary orbits") at a certain discrete set of distances from
>    the nucleus. These orbits are associated with definite energies and
>    are also called energy shells or energy levels. In these orbits, the
>    electron's acceleration does not result in radiation and energy loss
>    as required by classical electromagnetics. The Bohr model of an atom
>    was based upon Planck's quantum theory of radiation.

And the thing is that Bohr's model **did work** reasonably well for the hydrogen atom.

Later on scientist discovered that things which worked were just a coincidence, and some other things were just wrong. However, it was probably a necessary step in the way to QM.