# Why don’t electrons fall into the nucleus of an atom?

Tags: electromagnetism, atoms

The nuclei of atoms are composed of protons and neutrons. The proton has a positive charge, and the neutron a neutral charge. Shells of electrons outside the nucleus in the atom orbit around the nucleus. Here is my question: *If the protons in the nucleus possess a rival charge to the electron, why doesn’t the electron become attracted to the proton(s) in the nucleus and hence fall “into” the atom?*

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times, see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20003/why-dont-electrons-crash-into-the-nuclei-they-orbit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sun attracts the Earth, so why don't we fall into the Sun? There is a different problem for the atom, though. When electrons accelerate, they give off energy as photons. Orbiting in a circle is still form of acceleration, so the electron should lose all of its orbital energy and *then* fall into the nucleus. This doesn't happen, so we know that the orbiting electron picture is wrong. Quantum mechanics tells us the electrons act like waves around the nucleus.

Comment: I see. That's also why scientists say that quantum mechanics cannot be compared to the real world in any physical or logical state.

Comment: In an s state such as the ground state of hydrogen the electron moves radially with respect to the nucleus, if such a classical image applies at all. So in fact the electron should pass through the nucleus but with high kinetic energy.