# How can an ion ever capture an electron if an electron requires a precise momentum to match a subsequent orbital?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, atoms, orbitals

Suppose an electron approaches a proton with greater energy than the hydrogen ground state. Will the electron scatter? If so, how could an electron ever be captured given it would require *exactly* the right momentum?

If the electron is instead captured, what happens to the excess kinetic energy?

Is there a threshold at which the energy difference is too great, or will all electrons in the nucleus' vicinity be captured (provided there is a vacancy in the valence shell)?

Comment: by "captured" do you mean: collide into the proton/neutron core of the atom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't electrons crash into the nuclei they "orbit"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20003/why-dont-electrons-crash-into-the-nuclei-they-orbit)

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "ion" not "atom". I'm not referring to "electron capture" (electron colliding with the nucleus), but an ion achieving stability by capturing an electron in a valance shell.

Comment: The excess energy may be given off in the form of photons

Comment: Does this mean that almost all ion neutralisations (not sure of correct term) will emit photons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The electron *can* be captured; the excess kinetic energy is carried off by the emitted photon. This, for example, is why spectrum of hydrogen recombination has "continua" such as the [Lyman continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyman_continuum_photons): the capture of electrons with zero velocity produces photons with energy equal to the ionization potential, with a continuum of higher-energy photons from the capture of electrons with nonzero velocities (the individual photons have energies = ionization potential + electron's kinetic energy).

The cross-section for electron capture is, for hydrogen ions (i.e., bare protons) at least, an inverse function of the electron's velocity squared. So slow-moving electrons are more easily captured, but there isn't a strict threshold: some fast-moving electrons will be captured.