# How come subatomic particles interact with each other while not being in contact?

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, charge, interactions, locality

Although electrons stays away from protons an atom remains electrically neutral
But two atoms one positively charged and another negatively charged remain so until they comes in contact.
Can the modern atomic model be wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't electrons crash into the nuclei they "orbit"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/)

Answer (score 1):

The electromagnetic *field* allows charged particles to interact with each other without being in contact. It pervades the space *between* the charged particles (and everywhere else).

The modern atomic model works extremely well. It is one of the triumphs of physics!

Comment: @safesphere Your idea that there is no electromagnetic field in quantum mechanics is far from the mainstream. In fact, it is *extremely common* to formulate the quantum mechanics of charged particles using an *unquantized* electromagnetic field. What do you think the electrostatic potential in the Schrodinger equation of the hydrogen atom represents? How do you think spin-orbit coupling is explained? Or the Stark effect? Or the Zeeman effect? Atomic structure has virtually *nothing* to do with QED. However, QED *is* necessary for understanding transitions *between* atomic states.

Comment: @safesphere There have been numerous discussions on this site about how to think about Feynman diagrams and virtual particles. Your “no fields..., only particles in direct contact” view is in the minority. The general consensus is that the “intuition” gained from taking Feynman diagrams literally as you do is harmful to understanding quantum **field** theory. There is a lot of room for improvement in your answer as well, since it does not yet exist. Why not write one?