# Why an electron does not get stuck to nucleus?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals, stability

An electron remains in its orbit because of electrostatic and centrifugal force. But when a reaction takes place some electrons are gained or removed. Then how they still are stable?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

An electron is removed or added in outer orbitals. There is slight variation in Z_eff. but overall the total energy of electron - proton system remains negative which makes the electron bounded around the nucleus.