# Why low energy electron-proton colision cannot simply produce neutrons?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, collision, protons

Can low energy electron-proton collision produce neutrons (and neutrinos)? I asked many of my physics teachers but they said that it would produce hydrogen atoms instead. Some explained this because of strong interactions and some explained using weak nuclear interactions, but actually i didn't understand anything. Why the colliding particles pair energies has to be very high in order to collide and produce neutrons? isn't the electrostatic forces between them strong enough to attract them into each other? Are there any short-range forces which is stronger than electrostatic forces which prevents them simply from getting that near to each other?

Comment: How much energy is released in the decay of a free neutron?

Comment: it is another way of asking  "why dont elcctrons crash into the nucleus https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20003/why-dont-electrons-crash-into-the-nuclei-they-orbit/20004#20004