# Why don't electrons and protons collide inside Atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, protons

I was thinking of atoms. Usually atoms have same amount of electrons and protons. While electrons are negatively charged and Protons are positively charged. As we know from **coulomb's law** that positive and negative charge always attracts and (positive and positive) or (negative and negative) distract. So, they should collide inside atom also. I was searching on Google little bit. I found in Google that while electrons and protons come closer and closer they form mesons. While I was writing the question I found a related question to this in [Quora](https://qr.ae/pGIN0d).

> An electron can't be compared to a planet, and must instead be thought of as a kind of cloud of probability

Electron is particle and it has wavelike behavior also. Is it the reason of not to collide? I didn't get the answer of Quora. While it is particle it must have to collide. I found another related question in [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/51576).

> They do collide. But it's not like cars crashing and smashing each other up on the highway. Their quantum mechanical wavefunctions overlap and the electrons do in face settle in with wavefunctions that are centered on the nucleus.

If they collide than why atoms aren't vanishing? What type of collision is happening inside Atom? As I wrote earlier if they collide, they form mesons that's what I got in Google. But, I am unable to understand the collision inside Atom? What's happening right there?

Comment: my answer here should cover it https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/

Comment: @annav So, does it like we(I) are getting the wrong(thinking of the correct model wrong way) model?

Comment: @Istiak you are thining classical electricity and magnetism. Physics has progressed to quantum mechanics, exactly because the fact that atoms exist cannot be explained with classical mechanics and electrodynamics.

Comment: @annav Thanks...