# Why do electrons orbit the nucleus instead of just sticking to it?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, atoms, orbitals

If the electron stays on the nucleus because of electrostatic charge, why do they spin around instead of just staying there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't electrons crash into the nuclei they "orbit"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/)

Comment: Does the linked duplicate answer your question? You might also be asking about the existence of bound states with zero angular momentum — that is, $\ell=0$, also known as $s$-wave states.

Comment: A related classical-physics question would be why does the Earth orbit the Sun instead of falling into it.