Why should an electron falling into the nucleus, according to the Maxwell's laws of electrodynamics, destroy the atom?
It is often said in physics and chemistry classes and textbooks that atoms must be unstable when the electron continuously loses energy and finally fall into the nucleus according to classical physics. They often give an impression that the two when combined would annihilate into energy.
I am of the understanding that such a model of atom is unstable (with the electrons revolving around the nucleus in circular paths) and we need a better explanation.
Strictly within the ambit of classical physics, does it predict the annihilation of atom into energy? Protons and electrons are not matter and anti-matter they why should they get annihilated when the latter falls into the former?

There's no concept of annihilation in classical EM.

Thanks for the reply. Then in what sense do they say that atoms must be unstable?

The answer given below is what you are looking for. If you want more information you can find details under the name "Bremsstrahlung"

have a look at this relevant question and answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20003/why-dont-electrons-crash-into-the-nuclei-they-orbit?rq=1

They often give an impression that the two when combined would annihilate into energy. - No, that is not what is meant.
Classically because the electrons are charged and accelerating, the electrons would be losing energy by the emission of a continuous spectrum of electromagnetic radiation and thus spiral into the nucleus (cf satellite entering the atmosphere).
If the electrons spiral into the nucleus, what is the end result?
No longer an "atom" but a very small neutral mass.

The neutral mass becomes arbitrarily large negative.

Thanks Farcher for the response!

Jan Lalinsky - I didn't understand your comment. Could you kindly elaborate?

@Learner the electron loses an infinite amount of energy while spiraling into the nucleus (because of the singularity in the Coulomb's law). Ján's comment assumes the special-relativistic relation between mass and energy and the conservation of total energy of the whole system: nucleus+electron+radiation.

If that is the case, no two opposite charges can come touching each other? Like oppositely charged ions in an ionic solid? Or it is only a special case about the electron and the nucleus? Is there a similar singularity in case of an attractive force between magnets also? Does an electron and proton approaching each other in a straight line accelerate towards each other? If yes, does the electron radiate EM waves in that case also?

@Ruslan - What you said is true if the electron and proton are assumed to be point charges? Does classical physics make such an assumption? They may be very small but are they assumed to be of zero size? Or is it some other law of electrodynamics that predicts the electron to lose an infinite amount of energy in the form of EM waves?

@Learner yes, they have to be assumed to be point-like, otherwise all sorts of problems appear, because perfectly rigid bodies are impossible in relativity (and relativity is necessary for a correct description of classical EM). As for touching of the point charges, this is the realm of quantum physics, here you can't apply classical EM anymore. The quantum-mechanical (S-wave) solutions for the proton+electron system predict a nonzero probability density of touching. But the rules there are very different from classical EM (though there is the correspondence principle that connects the two).

@Ruslan - 'Touching of the point charges is the realm of quantum physics' - Does this mean ions are treated as point charges and ionic bond formation and classical physics can't even explain the formation of seemingly simple ionic bond? Or this singularity is not an issue in case of the formation of ionic bond as ions are not treated as point charges?

@Learner no, ions are treated as systems of nuclei and electrons, which are definitely not point-like. E.g. $\mathrm{He}^{+}$ is described the same way as the hydrogen atom. As for classical explanation of the bonds, indeed, it doesn't exist simply due to the fact that even the atom doesn't have a classical explanation. This includes any type of bond: ionic, covalent, hydrogenic etc.


It is often said in physics and chemistry classes and textbooks that atoms must be unstable when the electron continuously loses energy and finally fall into the nucleus according to classical physics.

The usual model of hydrogen atom in EM theory has some assumptions: the "electron" (lighter negative charge) orbits the "proton" (much heavier positive charge). The electron experiences force from the proton and from itself (self-force), but there are no other external forces; in particular, there isn't any background radiation acting on these charged particles. Also, it is assumed energy in the system flows according to the usual interpretation of the Poynting theorem.
In this model, the negative charge actually gains kinetic energy as it falls down to the nucleus. But during this fall, electric potential energy of the system (positive charge + negative charge) decreases more. So as a whole, energy of the system decreases, and this energy gets away with EM radiation. After some short time, it becomes zero and if the process continues, decreases further to negative values. Due to relation between energy and mass in relativistic theory $E=mc^2$, the system comes to a state where it has zero mass, and then negative mass.
The "atom must be unstable" means this electron fall to the nucleus happens in a very short time, around nanoseconds. We have never detected this with hydrogen atom.

They often give an impression that the two when combined would annihilate into energy.
Strictly within the ambit of classical physics, does it predict the annihilation of atom into energy? Protons and electrons are not matter and anti-matter they why should they get annihilated when the latter falls into the former?

They do not annihilate in the sense of matter+antimatter particles disappearing and EM radiation appearing, like with quantum model of positronium. In the above classical model of hydrogen, the particles just get arbitrarily closer to each other, and radiate arbitrarily large amount of EM energy.

Thanks for the response Ján Lalinský!!! Then would a proton and an electron approaching each other linearly (on a straight line) would lose energy in a similar fashion and get into this negative mass scenario?

I think it depends on the model of self-force, there are some papers arguing that self-force on the electron (and proton) prevents the collapse, but I don't think they are correct. Intuitively, the collapse is inevitable in the usual model. Either assumption on EM fields has to change, or other EM fields (background radiation) has to be present, to prevent the collapse.

In that case, we can't guess using classical physics alone what would happen to the hydrogen atom, if it radiated energy as predicted by Maxwell's laws? We don't know if it will be a neutral lump of a definite mass or a neutral lump with an knowably large negative mass (whatever negative mass means in classical physics) or disappear into energy (in some sense if not in the matter & antimatter sense).

Negative mass means the system accelerates in the opposite direction to that of the external force.

Thanks  Ján Lalinský! I understand that there is no definitive answer for this question.


It is often said in physics and chemistry classes and textbooks that atoms must be unstable when the electron continuously loses energy and finally fall into the nucleus according to classical physics.

Not "...must be unstable when..." but "...would be unstable if..."
It was plainly obvious at the beginning of the 20th century that electrons do not spiral into their atomic nuclei because all of chemistry depends on the electronic structure of atoms and molecules. They understood that none of the physical substances of which our world is made could exist if the electronic "cloud" surrounding each nucleus was unstable.

I am of the understanding that such a model of atom is unstable (with the electrons revolving around the nucleus in circular paths) and we need a better explanation.

That's the heart of the problem. Maxwell's theories predict that an orbiting electron must radiate its energy away. Therefore, whatever the electron cloud actually is,  it cannot be "electrons revolving around the nucleus in circular paths."

Strictly within the ambit of classical physics, does it predict the annihilation of atom into energy?

I have not heard that classical physics makes any prediction regarding the fate of electrons that spiral into nuclei. And why would they bother to predict the consequences of a thing that they knew does not happen?
If electrons spiraled into nuclei (which, they don't) then atoms would cease to be atoms anymore (which, they don't) and the Earth itself would never have existed (which, it does) and so it doesn't really matter what the atoms would have turned into if they turned into anything else at all (which, they don't.)

That is precisely my point, if any prediction can't be made about the fate of the atom classically assuming the electrons going around the nucleus in circular paths, then why say the atoms cease to be atoms and the earth wouldn't exist. Does it mean that matter wouldn't exist at all or it doesn't exist in the form it is now like stars, planets, oceans, humans, food etc?

If atoms cease to be atoms what would they be? Energy or miniature atoms that are neutral blobs of mass like the Dalton's atom?

@Learner, Re, "If atoms cease to be atoms, what would they be?" You've missed my point, which is, that physicists don't bother with questions like that. It's like asking a zoologist which way a unicorn's horn would spiral if unicorns were real. zoologists are more interested in creatures that are real. Physicists are more interested in explaining the reasons for phenomena that do happen. They don't generally speculate about the consequences of phenomena that don't happen.

P.S., Dalton did not know about electrons. We're actually talking about a very short slice of history here. 1897: Thompson discovers electrons. 1908: Rutherford, et al proclaim that atoms have a tiny, positively charged nucleus surrounded by an electron cloud. 1913: Bohr suggests that electrons orbit the nucleus like planets orbiting a star, but he is already aware that, according to Maxwell's theory, they should then radiate away all of their energy, and he is working on the problem of why that doesn't happen. From the mid 1920s on, atomic theory is pure quantum mechanics.

I agree. It predicts that the electron spirals all the way into the nucleus and for this reason we say it is unstable and we don't have to care what would have happened after it fell into the nucleus as that was hypothetical.

The protons and electrons do not annihilate. They combine to form neutrons. When a neutron star forms, the enormous pressure from a supernova explosion forces the electrons into the nucleus. The enormous force required to combine protons with electrons indicates this is not a spontaneous natural process. The electrons and protons combine to form neutrons and this is probably what would happen if the electron was to somehow fall into the nucleus. A nucleus composed purely of neutrons is almost certainly unstable, because nuclei composed entirely of neutrons are never observed in nature. Nuclei appear to require protons to hold the nucleus together and (as Learner has pointed out in the comments) neutrons are unstable in the absence of protons.

In case of a hydrogen atom, it would result in a single neutron that is unstable (half life of about 10 mins?) and is likely to decay back into a proton and an electron with the emission of an antineutrino?

@Learner You are right. A single neutron is unstable and decays quite quickly.
